# Old Raid1 working on new Ubuntu Server install?

Tags: server, raid, mdadm

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 over my old 16.04 install. I had a Raid1 config in my old setup, which I administered through mdadm. It seems as if my Raid1 config is still present in the 18.04 install (see below).

```
NAME    FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
loop0   squashfs           86.9M /snap/core/4917   
loop1   squashfs             87M /snap/core/5145   
sda                        57.6G                   
├─sda1                        1M                   
└─sda2  ext4               57.6G /                 
sdb                         1.8T                   
└─sdb1  linux_raid_member   1.8T                   homeserver:0
  └─md0 ext4                1.8T /media/raiddrives 
sdc                         1.8T                   
└─sdc1  linux_raid_member   1.8T                   homeserver:0
  └─md0 ext4                1.8T /media/raiddrives 
sdd                       931.5G                   
└─sdd1  ext4              931.5G                   
sr0                        1024M
```

My question is: What do I need to do in order to have this Raid1 working as before? Do I need to update the mdadm.conf or is it enough just to mount the md0 drive the way it was before? I have now temporarily mounted it at /media/raiddrives.

While I am at it, I would like to post a different but somehow related question. Can I use my current Raid1 config if I where to setup only a Raspberry Pi Owncloud server with e.g. Ubuntu Core? What would be the optimal setup for a NAS using the existing Raid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is usually nothing to configure when migrating an existing **mdadm** based RAID array to a new machine, `mdadm` should just detect and activate your RAID array.

In this case, your RAID have been detected as `/dev/md0` and you have been able to mount it under `/media/raiddrives`.

I can only recommend to have a look at the output of `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0`, and verify that the **State** is **clean** as in the following example :

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Aug  6 14:29:19 2016
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 104841216 (99.98 GiB 107.36 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 104841216 (99.98 GiB 107.36 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Aug 14 13:49:15 2018
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : EDITED_HOSTNAME:0  (local to host EDITED_HOSTNAME)
           UUID : 772e6cc4:5af56198:1f0a2ec5:141b3e7e
         Events : 4832

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       3       8        2        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda2
       2       8       18        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: Thanks, that is reassuring to know. So, what would be my best bet for a NAS? Should I continue with Ubuntu Server, which has worked well for a number of years (never tried to make it available in the cloud though) or should I go with OpenMediaVault or some other dedicated NAS OS?